# Load large bitmap from url and resize it

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-image, bitmapimage

I want load huge image from url and show on my device. I read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) post for doing this.

In that example they use native drawable but I want get image from server.

I am using this code

```
 private void getBitmap(ImageView imageView,final String url){

        mBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        mBitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        URL mUrl = null;
        InputStream is= null;
        try {
            mUrl = new URL(url);
            is = mUrl.openStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,mBitmapOptions);

        mCurrentBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmapOptions.outWidth,
                mBitmapOptions.outHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        mBitmapOptions.inBitmap = mCurrentBitmap;
        mBitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,mBitmapOptions);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mCurrentBitmap);
//        Bitmap croppedBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(mCurrentBitmap, 0, mCurrentBitmap.getHeight()/2, mCurrentBitmap.getWidth(), mCurrentBitmap.getHeight()/2));
//        imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
    }
```

I want here get image from url and resize it but I have an exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

What I did wrong here? or could you suggest me better answer?

Comment: Thank you @Damian but Picasso automatically handles large image loading or should I do it my own?

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,mBitmapOptions);` that you commented is here to actually fill width and height in bitmapoptions. You'd best download the file first, then perform this operation on the file.

Comment: @njzk2 there is several images that have large size it's not a best way I think download all images after that perferm operation.

Comment: you'll have to download them anyway, you know. as you cannot a/ know their size or b/ display them without downloading them

Comment: @njzk2 no you do not have to download the whole image before knowing the size (the size of the image that is, the actual byte count is harder), look for instance on this answer: [getting-the-size-of-an-image-inputstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213676/getting-the-size-of-an-image-inputstream) it's' using mark/reset technique to read some of the inputstream to know the size before reading the whole image.

Comment: @pmb You get the exception becuase of `//     BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,mBitmapOptions);` there are no mBitmapOptions set when you try to decode. Look at my previous answer to try to resolve your complete decoding issue.

Answer (score 4):

I would use Picasso, then what you want to achieve is as simple as this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(50, 50).into(imageView)
```

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because of:

```
// BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,mBitmapOptions);
```

There are no mBitmapOptions set when you try to call:

```
mCurrentBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmapOptions.outWidth, mBitmapOptions.outHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Have a look at the answer in this question to further optimize your code: [Getting the size of an image inputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213676/getting-the-size-of-an-image-inputstream)

Answer (score 0):

I developped a solution based on http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html tutorial. Here is my code. The tricky part consist of using a byte array to store image data (because unfortunatly `markSupported`() is not available for `connection.getInputStream()`).

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(final String imageUrl, final Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        final InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        // using byte array to prevent open 2 times a stream
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input, 4*1024);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte)current);
        }
        bis.close();
        byte[] imageData = baf.toByteArray();
        if(options != null){
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options optionsSize = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            optionsSize.inJustDecodeBounds = true;


            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, optionsSize);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(optionsSize, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            optionsSize.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        }
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        if(options == null){
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
        }
        else{
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);
        }
        // close the stream;
        input.close();
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Hope it will helps you.